# asp.net http GET sending data by AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, controller

I'm trying to send data from AJAX GET to my controller, but the data is always null.

My Controller:

```
    [Route("api/sendingData")]
public class myController : ApiController
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [HttpGet]
    public bool Get(dataModel data)
    {
        myFunc result = new myFunc(data);

        return result.success;
    }
}
```

My dataModel:

```
    public class dataModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<int> arrValues { get; set; } = null;
}
```

I call the controller by html ajax:

```
    data = {
    id: 1,
    arrValues : [40, 43]
};
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "api/sendingData",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            console.debug(result);
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
            console.debug(xhr);
            var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
            alert(err);
        }
    });
```

When I debug my controller, the variable data is null. Why isn't it getting the data from the AJAX request?

Thanks

Comment: Change your ajax to type: "POST" and decorate your backend method with HTTPPost, you are posting data to the server, hence the reason to use "POST"

Comment: I need GET because I need to use jsonp (cross servers)

Comment: Is this controller not hosted on the same server as the website which you are posting data from?

Comment: No. Data is coming from a ColdFusion server and the controller is in Azure server

Comment: Why not just enable CORS, which kind of looks like whats going on...

Comment: I enabled CORS and it still returning cors blocked

Answer (score 0):

Model don't need to assign null on dataModel class.

```
public class dataModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<int> arrValues { get; set; } 
}
```

Change your controller to accept primitive types like int and string , since a get request and then send data to get request from ajax using query string.

```
[Route("api/sendingData")]
        public class myController : ApiController
        {
            [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
            [HttPGet]
            public bool Get(int id, string commaSeparatedValues)
            {
                var data = new dataModel { id = id, arrValues = commaSeparatedValues.Split(',').Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).ToList()};
                myFunc result = new myFunc(data);

                return result.success;
            }
        }


$.ajax(
    {
        url: "api/sendingData?id="+1+"&arrValues='1,2,3,4'",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            console.debug(result);
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
            console.debug(xhr);
            var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
            alert(err);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I need GET because I need to use jsonp (cross servers)

Comment: Ok ,Updating answer now ,will post in 5 mins.

Comment: It is returning "Loading failed for the <script> with source "

Comment: What's your request look like? Can you sent the request URL from chrome developer tool(Network tab)?

Comment: Using Firefox it returns: Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://myServer/api/sendingData?id=1&Units=40,43&callback=jQuery1124034264046751600574_1518044067750&_=1518044067751”.

Comment: wrap  inside inside '' , like arrValues='1,2,3,4'". Updated the answer

Comment: Odd... but it returns the same error with arrValues=%2740,43%27& it changes the ' to % in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like type: "POST".
When you have type: "GET", your date goes into your url like below:

```
api/sendingData?id=1&arrValues=value
```

Comment: I need get because I need jsonp (cross servers)